# How to navigate through the app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have an iOS app which has the following internal structure:
[image]

So **R** is the root view controller (sort of main menu screen), user can proceed to settings screen (**S**) and then to either **A** or **B** view controllers.

The task sounds rather simple: when push notification comes (and user tapped on it), application must show **A** view controller to the user.

I can think of two ways how to handle it.

The first is to find out the currently active view controller, and then use logic like this:

If **A** is the currently visible view controller, then nothing needs to be done.

If **B** is the current, then it need to be dismissed (thus routing to **S**) and then **A** must be presented immediately. And user must not see that **S** appears even for a short time.

And so on.

The second way it to dismiss/pop everything until getting to the root **R**. And then push **S** and present **A**.

Do my thoughts make sense, and what would you suggest?

Particularly, I am interested in

1. how to realize which view controller is "the current" at given moment
2. how to perform routing **B**->dismiss->**S**->present **A** quickly and without showing **S**.

Answer (score 0):

Answers :-

1- To know what is the current active viewController keep a shared userDefault boolean value called isAactive by default it's false in viewDidLoad make it true and in viewDidDisappear make it false again and same for all like isBactive and so on , check it wherever you are

2- When notification comes while B is active use delagate or NotificationCenter to inform viewController S (listener) to colse B if active and present A like that

```
  dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

  // present A make animation false
```

or If you make it also push from S to A and B

so you will pop the current if it's B and push A

**note:** you can use setViewControllers method of navigationController to set array of viewControllers anywhere which removes the current stack of viewControllers and replace them with new array that you set , that will keep your head high from checking current and achieve the goal

Answer (score 0):

I do mine like this when receiving notifications for our calendar events. I negate the call, so it only fires when the user /isn't/ on the Calendar view. Also, this is a push onto an existing nav stack, which may not be the behavior you want. If you want to rebuild the nav stack, you'd want to call `navController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)` before the push.

**AppDelegate**

```
func pushCalendarView() {

    let navController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let calendarView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CalendarView") as! CalendarViewController

    // !negated
    if let controller = navController.visibleViewController, !controller.isKind(of: CalendarViewController.self) {

        navController.pushViewController(calendarView, animated: true)
    }
}
```